# Angular-UI routing reloading template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using the angular-ui Routing, but when nesting it keeps loading the main index file over and over again I think, I'm working in Visual Studio and it starts lagging when I go to that page, but the other ones are no problem

this is the code in routing:

```
$stateProvider
    .state("stateOne", {
        url: "/stateOne",
        templateUrl: "/routesDemo/one"

    })
    .state("stateTwo", {
        url: "/stateTwo?donuts",
        templateUrl: function(params) { return "/routesDemo/two?donuts=" + params.donuts; }
    })
    .state("stateThree", {
        url: "/stateThree",
        templateUrl: "/routesDemo/three"

    })
    .state("stateAllProducts", {
        url: "/Products",
        templateUrl: "/product/all",
        controller: ProductJsController

    })
    .state("loginRegister", {
        url: "/loginRegister?returnUrl",
        views: {
            "": {
                templateUrl: "/Account/LoginRegister",
            },
            "login@loginRegister": {
                templateUrl: "/Account/Login",
                controller: LoginController
            },
            "register@loginRegister": {
                templateUrl: "/Account/Register",
                controller: RegisterController
            }
        }
    });
```

The content of LoginRegister is as following:

```
<div ui-view="login"></div>

<div ui-view="register"></div>
```

Login

```
  <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="bs-component">
            <form class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="login()">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Login</legend>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="emailAddress" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <div class="form-control-wrapper">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control empty" ng-model="loginForm.emailAddress" id="emailAddress" placeholder="Email"><span class="material-input"></span></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Password</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <div class="form-control-wrapper">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control empty" ng-model="loginForm.password" id="password" placeholder="Password"><span class="material-input"></span></div>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="loginForm.rememberMe"><span class="ripple"></span><span class="check"></span> Remember me?
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                            <button class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
            <div id="source-button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" style="display: none;">
                &lt; &gt;
                <div class="ripple-wrapper"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-danger" ng-if="loginForm.loginFailure">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" ng-click="closeError()">×</button>
            <strong>Oh snap!</strong> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="alert-link">Change a few things up</a> and try submitting again.
        </div>
    </div>
```

Register

```
<form ng-submit="register()">
    <label for="emailAddress">Email Address:</label>
    <input id="emailAddress" type="text" ng-model="registerForm.emailAddress" required/>

    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input id="password" type="password" ng-model="registerForm.password" required/>

    <label for="confirmPassword">Confirm Password:</label>
    <input id="confirmPassword" type="password" ng-model="registerForm.confirmPassword" required/>

    <button type="submit">Register</button>
</form>

<div ng-if="loginForm.registrationFailure">
    D'oh!
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the index HTML file. Your view may not be able to be rendered if you controller is not loading. Please also provide one of your controller files.

You need to enclose your controller names in quotes, the same way they are in the controller.

```
.state("stateAllProducts", {
        url: "/Products",
        templateUrl: "/product/all",
        controller: ProductJsController
```

Looks like it should be:

```
.state("stateAllProducts", {
        url: "/Products",
        templateUrl: "/product/all",
        controller: 'ProductJsController'
```

Without seeing more code, this is the best I can provide.